# How to inject JavaScript inside JSX attribute's string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to put some default props inside `className=" px-6 py-2 bg-black rounded-full text-black "`
and when I use this component elsewhere I will be passing background or text color as props.

What's the right syntax for this manipulation?

I was trying to use grave accent ` with classic ${} but it doesn't work out in my react application.

```js
<button className=`btn px-6 py-2 bg-${} rounded-full`>
  shop
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use a JSX expression, which is `{expression}` (in a JSX context). So you might well use a template literal, within the `{}`, like this (assuming `backgroundColor` and `textColor` contain the props):

```
return (
    <Button className={`px-6 py-2 bg-${backgroundColor} text-${textColor}`}>
        ...
    </Button>
);
```

It doesn't have to be a template literal, it could be a string concatenation expression:

```
return (
    <Button className={"px-6 py-2 bg-" + backgroundColor + " text-" + textColor}>
        ...
    </Button>
);
```

Or to keep the JSX from getting to hard to work with, do it prior to the JSX:

```
const theClass = `px-6 py-2 bg-${backgroundColor} text-${textColor}`;
return (
    <Button className={theClass}>
        ...
    </Button>
);
```